# Maintain a counter in one table to track INSERT and DELETE in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, concurrency

I have a Spring Boot application with Postgres as database and Hibernate for persistence management. There are two tables in the db: STATISTICS and USER. Client machines submit entries to STATISTICS table and there is a 'counter' column in USER table to keep track of number of entries in the other table(increment on insert and decrement on delete).

I started with a basic query to maintain the counter: `UPDATE USER u set u.counter = coalesce(u.counter, 0) + <update_by> where u.id = <user_id>`. The <update_by> would be negative for deletion.

My questions:

1. Do I need to obtain explicit locks(something like SELECT...FOR UPDATE) to ensure concurrent updates don't work with stale data and overwrite other update's changes?
2. Would a database trigger be a better choice to maintain this counter? If yes, do I need to take care of locking for concurrent updates there?

(I need to maintain the counter along with the changes to other table and not do the count by going over the whole table when it is requested)

Answer (score 0):

postgresql already blocks updatable records, you can use a trigger or a function, both are executed in the one transaction, blocking updatable records